# Url Mapping: Don't want to have to type Index in the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute

I have the following URL map in Global.asax.cs:

```
 routes.MapRoute("RejectRevision", "{controller}/{Index}/{revisionId}"
        , new { controller = "RejectRevision", action = "Index", revisionId = "" });
```

But I don't want to have to type http://localhost:9999/RejectRevision/Index/1, I want to be able to type in http://localhost:9999/RejectRevision/1 in order to hit the Index action on the RejectRevision controller.  What am I missing here?

THanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before your `Default` route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "RejectRevision",
    "{controller}/{revisionId}",
    new { 
        controller = "RejectRevision", 
        action = "Index", 
        revisionId = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If this is placed before your `Default` route, a request of `/RejectRevision/1` will map to `RejectRevisionController.Index()` action method.

Or, if this is the only Controller/Action method you want to be mapped like this, then you can use a literal instead of a parameter for the route:

```
routes.MapRoute( 
    "RejectRevision", 
    "RejectRevision/{revisionId}", 
    new {  
        controller = "RejectRevision",  
        action = "Index",  
        revisionId = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

Comment: ty.  what is the significance of putting this before the Default route?

Comment: @gangelo The significance of putting this before the Default route is because routes are analyzed sequentially, and the first match is the route that is utilized.